# Count number of instances in Excel based on another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif

I want to count the number of times a name appears with "Yes" in the next column.

Table sample:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula to use for that will be `COUNTIFS`, which lets you do a count based on multiple ranges and multiple criteria.

For your example the exact formula would be:

```
=COUNTIFS(B1:B1000,E1,C1:C1000,"Yes")
```

Where `E1` is a cell with one of the names, and then `E2` for the next name, and so on.

See sample here:

[image]

And here you could see the formulas:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a PivotTable:

1. Put headers on your 2 existing columns (e.g. "Name" and "Y/N")
2. Add a 3rd Column "Count" and fill it with "1" all the way down
3. "Insert" tab -> PivotTable. It should automatically select your data. Hit OK.
4. In the "PivotTable Fields" sidebar: Drag "Name" to the Rows area, "Y/N" in Columns, and "Count" in Values